# Convert control to Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

We had this button on our site:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button-loading-example" 
      ng-click="progress.buttonLoading.load()" 
      ng-model="progress.buttonLoading" pb-button-progress
      type="button">Save</button>
```

The ng-model linked to this, in the controller (controller as "progress"):

```
 _this.buttonLoading = {
  isLoading: false,
  text: 'Saving',
  load: function() {
    _this.buttonLoading.isLoading = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      _this.buttonLoading.isLoading = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
};
```

I am trying to make this a directive.  I can pass the classes and the label from my element:

```
<pb-spinner-button ng-class-list="btn btn-primary">Save</pb-spinner-button>
```

I cannot figure out how to wire up (or simply discard and supersede) the ng-model and, worse, I don't know where to hook into the "load" function in the old controller.

I realize it's very possible the old control was very overdone and should have been a Directive, but who I inherited from was directive-averse.

Here's my directive so far:

```
  (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').directive('pbSpinnerButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        ngClassList: '@'

      },
      controller: 'SpinnerController',
      template: '<button class="{{ngClassList}}" ng-click="buttonLoading.load()" ng-model="buttonLoading" pb-button-progress type="button"><ng-transclude></button>',
      transclude: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  })


  .controller('SpinnerController', function($timeout) {

    var _this = this;
    _this.buttonLoading = {
      isLoading: false,
      text: 'Saving',
      load: function() {
        _this.buttonLoading.isLoading = true;
        $timeout(function() {
          _this.buttonLoading.isLoading = false;
        }, 2000);
      }
    };

  });

})();
```

As requested, here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EOekzFdUDrArZ4dkolLl?p=preview

Comment: no model being passed to attributes but since it's a button do you need ng-model? .. create a demo in plunker.

Comment: This is part of what I don't understand.  Here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/EOekzFdUDrArZ4dkolLl?p=preview

Comment: well the error thrown is due to no ng-model being passed. For `type=button` I can't see any use whatsoever for ng-model...is just a UI button

Comment: also not good practice using `ng-` prefix... implies a core directive

Comment: main issue I see right now is controller is using `controllerAs` scoping but you haven't declared `controllerAs` in directive. [Simple demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EOekzFdUDrArZ4dkolLl?p=preview) getting load function to create alert:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't believe that ng-model serves any purpose in a button. If the intent is to set the text value of the button dynamically, then you should use this approach:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button-loading-example" 
  ng-click="progress.buttonLoading.load()" 
  pb-button-progress type="button">{{progress.buttonLoading.text}}</button>
```

Also, your directive template doesn't seem to be using ng-transclude correctly, and custom directives and their attributes shouldn't use the 'ng-' prefix.

Here's an example implementation of what I think you're looking for:

```
angular.module('app').directive('pbSpinnerButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button class="{{classList}}" ng-click="onClick()" pb-button-progress type="button" ng-transclude></button>',
    scope: {
      classList: '@',
      onClick: '&'
    },
    transclude: true
  };
});
```

Then include it in your controller template HTML:

```
<pb-spinner-button class-list="btn btn-primary"
  on-click="progress.buttonLoading.load()"
>{{progress.buttonLoading.text}}</pb-spinner-button>
```

You can view and run a simple implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/gagkbsra

Comment: I don't understand how the onClick makes the jump to the controller's function.

Comment: When you set on-click="progress.buttonLoading.load()", you're binding the controller's function to the on-click attribute, which is then stored in the directive's scope as 'onClick' (the camel case scope variable is converted to lowercase & dashes in html). So when you call onClick, you're actually executing the controller's function. The "onClick: '&'" in the directive's scope declaration indicates the onClick is a function.